# Error can't find email template with Titanium Alloy ACS

Tags: titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I am trying to use Titanium Alloy ACS to handle forgotten passwords.

In my controller I am running the following code:

```js
       this.config.Cloud.Users.requestResetPassword({
          email : usersEmail,
          template : "forgot_password"
        }, function(e) {
          if (e.success) {
            alert('You will receive an email soon with your password details.');
          } else {
            Ti.API.error(e);
            _callback && _callback({
              success : false,
              model : null,
              error : e
            });
          }
        });
```

On Appcelerator I have created an email template as follows:

[image]
The error I am getting is:

```html
[ERROR] :  422: Failed to send email: Email template forgot_password is not found
[ERROR] :  {
[ERROR] :      code = 422;
[ERROR] :      error = 1;
[ERROR] :      message = "Failed to send email: Email template forgot_password is not found";
[ERROR] :      success = 0;
[ERROR] :  }
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to me getting confused between the Appcelerator settings for the production version and the development version, once I had copied over the email template settings to the development version from the production version it worked fine.